# How to initialize logging in DLL

Tags: c#, logging, system.diagnostics

I have a DLL which will be used from a non-.NET application, so it doesn't appear that it will read a config file.
I've read solutions where you can code custom solutions to explicitly read the config from a DLL, but I don't see how to get the logging component to read that.
The config page for logging in System.Diagnostics claims that you can set everything from code. I have found how to create and add a listener.

```
    static LogFactory() {
        TextWriterTraceListener myListener = new TextWriterTraceListener("C:\\Logs\\app.log", "myListener");
        Trace.Listeners.Add(myListener);
        myListener.WriteLine("Test message.");
        Trace.WriteLine("Another test");
        myListener.Flush();
    }
```

The file is created but nothing gets written to it, either from this explicit write, or from any call to logging in the app.
TRACE is set in the build options.

Comment: How exactly is the DLL going to be used from the non-.NET application? How will they communicate?

Comment: @C.AugustoProiete Not sure why that matters, but as a COM object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your question how exactly is the DLL going to be used from the non-.NET application and how they are communicating with each other, but ideally the DLL would not have its own log... It would write to the log of the main app that is consuming it.

That means you would design your DLL in such a way that the consumer can provide you with a way to write to their logs (e.g. by passing an `ILogger` interface that are common/known by both DLL and host app, or at least a delegate of some kind e.g. `Action<string>`) through an agreed upon bootstrapping method that the host app would call as part of the bootstrapping of the app.

If you do decide to have a separate logging for the DLL without cooperation with the host app, then you could try using a [ModuleInitializer](https://einaregilsson.com/module-initializers-in-csharp/) which is a special function you can add to your .NET assembly that runs when the assembly is loaded for the first time.

As of this writing, an easy way to add ModuleInitializers to assemblies is through a Fody plugin called [ModuleInit](https://github.com/Fody/ModuleInit).

As for emitting the logs from within your DLL (regardless of the approach above), you might want to consider [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) or [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/) which offer a much more rich logging capabilities compared to Trace.

Comment: I generally never use Trace, for the reasons you mentioned. I was going with it this time because an SDK I'm using logs everything there and I wanted to keep everything together. But I've looked through their code now and every message that I really want, they log and then throw an exception. So it turns out that I'll get it anyway. So I'll just dump those and go with what I'm familiar with. Thanks!